# awk accepting variable supplied by dollar sign in cshell

Tags: awk, csh

In c shell script, I'm trying to pass bbb to awk sub, but apparently it does not work.

```
#!/bin/csh
set aaa=a
set bbb=b

#And I'm using it in awk sub

set ccc=`echo $aaa | awk '{sub("a",$bbb); print $0}'`

echo $ccc
```

But echos empty and dunno why.

Note if I replace $bbb with "b" then it works well.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the shell variable to `awk`.
Either with

```
set ccc=`echo $aaa | awk -v bb=$bbb '{sub("a",bb); print $0}'`
```

either close and reopen the `awk` quoting when referring to the shell variable :

```
set ccc=`echo $aaa | awk '{sub("a",'$bbb'); print $0}'`
```

Comment: Explanation: The shell (`csh`, `bash` etc) does not expand variable when in single tick quotes (`'$this_is_not_expanded'`).